# Turning off Directory Browsing

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

On the ColdFusion 10 built in webserver, how do you turn of directory browsing

Comment: Does the method described here not work with cf10?  http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/adv_development/config_builtin_webserver/config_builtin_webserver06.html

Comment: @DanBracuk, those are for JRun.

Comment: @james Mohler: I know this suggestion was good up to at least version 9, but you shouldn't be using the built in webserver on any kind of server beyond your local machine.  it was always highly suggested to go out and use a "real" software package like IIS or apache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's set in `[ColdFusion dir]/cfusion/runtime/web.xml`.

[Tomcat config docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/default-servlet.html).